# how can i interact with other preinstalled apps like WhatsApp using flutter?

Tags: flutter, automation, ui-automation

I am a flutter developer and I am trying to build a flutter app to send Whatsapp message just by clicking a button. Right now I am able to open the WhatsApp for a particular contact with a filled text box , but i am not able to hit the send button automatically.

Comment: Please see the solution on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63312503/i-want-to-launch-whatsapp-application-from-my-flutter-application

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this could be done for a Whatsapp Business Account not for a common user.
You will need some sort of user interaction to send the messages.
You can check information here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/overview